# How to add javascript to a wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Recently I found the following javascript from another thread on this forum;

```
var $content=$('div.leg_ol');
var $links=$('.leg_test').hover(function(){
var index= $links.index(this);
$content.stop(true,true).hide().eq(index).fadeIn();
},function(){
$content.stop(true,true).hide().eq(index);
});
```

(I would link to the OP, but unfortunately have lost the page).

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/mfyctwvs/1/

The code does exactly what I want to do - in theory, now I am pretty much completely new to js, so this is a very tricky area for me - please bear with me on this.

When I post the code in functions.php it causes my whole site to stop working, I assume because it cannot read it or there is some conflict?

So my first thought, looking at jsfiddle was the js version and that it is specified as no wrap in . If I change either of these the code does not work.. ..so 1. Am I making a newb mistake trying to include incompatible js in my functions.php (probably yes?) & 2. is there a straightforward change I can make to get this working in my functions.php?

I have been searching on this for hours & am sure that I could get this working with some adjustments?

FYI; Functions.php

```
  <?php// Set path to WooFramework and theme specific functions 
$functions_path = get_template_directory() . '/functions/';
$includes_path = get_template_directory() . '/includes/';

// Don't load alt stylesheet from WooFramework
if ( ! function_exists( 'woo_output_alt_stylesheet' ) ) {
function woo_output_alt_stylesheet () {}
}

// WooFramework
require_once ( $functions_path . 'admin-init.php' );    // Framework Init

if ( get_option( 'woo_woo_tumblog_switch' ) == 'true' ) {
//Enable Tumblog Functionality and theme is upgraded
update_option( 'woo_needs_tumblog_upgrade', 'false' );
update_option( 'tumblog_woo_tumblog_upgraded', 'true' );
update_option( 'tumblog_woo_tumblog_upgraded_posts_done', 'true' );
require_once ( $functions_path . 'admin-tumblog-quickpress.php' );  //   Tumblog Dashboard Functionality
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


$includes = array(
            'includes/theme-options.php',               // Options panel settings and custom settings
            'includes/theme-functions.php',             // Custom theme functions
            'includes/theme-actions.php',               // Theme actions & user defined hooks
            'includes/theme-comments.php',              // Custom comments/pingback loop
            'includes/theme-js.php',                    // Load JavaScript via wp_enqueue_script
            'includes/theme-plugin-integrations.php',   // Plugin integrations
            'includes/sidebar-init.php',                // Initialize widgetized areas
            'includes/theme-widgets.php',               // Theme widgets
            'includes/theme-advanced.php',              // Advanced Theme Functions
            'includes/theme-shortcodes.php',            // Custom theme shortcodes
            'includes/woo-layout/woo-layout.php',       // Layout Manager
            'includes/woo-meta/woo-meta.php',           // Meta Manager
            'includes/woo-hooks/woo-hooks.php'          // Hook Manager
            );

// Allow child themes/plugins to add widgets to be loaded.
$includes = apply_filters( 'woo_includes', $includes );

foreach ( $includes as $i ) {
locate_template( $i, true );
}

// Load WooCommerce functions, if applicable.
if ( is_woocommerce_activated() ) {
locate_template( 'includes/theme-woocommerce.php', true );
}

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* You can add custom functions below */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


 add_action( 'init', 'woo_custom_move_navigation', 10 );

function woo_custom_move_navigation () {
// Remove main nav from the woo_header_after hook
remove_action( 'woo_header_after','woo_nav', 10 );
// Add main nav to the woo_header_inside hook
add_action( 'woo_header_inside','woo_nav', 10 );
} // End woo_custom_move_navigation()

/* Testing stuff for mobile */
function woo_load_responsive_meta_tags () {
    $html = '';

    $html .= "\n" . '<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even      in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->' . "\n";
    $html .= '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />' . "\n";

    echo $html;
} // End woo_load_responsive_meta_tags()


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
wp_enqueue_script(
   'user-scripts', 
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/functions/user-scripts.js', 
   array('jquery') // any script dependancies. i.e. jquery
);
});
?>
```

Comment: "post the code in functions.php" javascript in a php script would cause it to break. can you show how you are using the js code in the php page?

Comment: Tbh I have never done it before so probably making all sorts of mistakes, I tried adding it as it was, which like you commented caused it to break (lesson one learned) Tried adding it like <script src="leg_hover.js"></script> but this did not work (I have the script saved as leg_hover.js).

Should I be referencing this file using something like 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'jsfunction();'
   , '</script>'
;

??

Comment: are you using wordpress? if so you'd need to [inject the script into your page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: From what you said it sounds like I need a php function to call the js?

Comment: you'd there are examples on the link. I'll post an answer

Comment: yeah I am. So would I include this in the page rather than in the functions.php? 

For example something like;
 <?php wp_enqueue_script( 'leg_hover', 'http://website/leg_hover.js', array(), false, false ); ?>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the script provided by @atmd the following code worked.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
wp_enqueue_script(
   'script-name', 
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/path-to-your-script.js', 
   array('jquery') // any script dependancies. i.e. jquery
);
});
```

A precondition required was that the script was located in the /functions/ folder of the theme used. The original code posted works perfectly on the site.

Comment: pls explain down vote reason if I am specifying this as the solution to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress you in ject your javascript files into your theme using the wordpress api/hooks. the method you want is `wp_enqueue_script`. [Here are the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

It's used like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScript');

function addScript() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
       'script-name', 
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/path-to-your-script.js', 
       array('jquery') // any script dependancies. i.e. jquery
    );
}
```

Depending on the version of php you have, you can inline the function:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script(
       'script-name', 
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/path-to-your-script.js', 
       array('jquery') // any script dependancies. i.e. jquery
    );
});
```

Comment: Ok, using add action makes sense. Then for the function I would assume I need to give the function a unique name so e.g. 'function leg_hover ()'? I will give this a try, the php makes sense at least! :)

Comment: one question - does the path need to be the full directory?

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri` will give you your theme directory, so you just need to add the path from there

Comment: tried the second one but this did not work, even starting with /canvas;


   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
     wp_enqueue_script(
       'leg_test', 
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/themes/canvas/user-scripts.js', 
       array('jquery') // any script dependancies. i.e. jquery
     );
    });

Comment: '/themes/canvas/' will be included in the value of `get_template_directory_uri()` try  get_template_directory_uri() . '/user-scripts.js' here are the docs on [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

Comment: number of function calls doesn't matter. maybe update the question with you functions.php and your directory structure

Comment: Functions.php added. Directory; /home3/aslginfo/public_html/sydneysustainableliving/wp-content/themes/canvas/functions/js/user-scripts.js

Comment: you've missed 'js' from your path ''/functions/user-scripts.js''

Comment: Yes - after I moved the script to the functions folder I forgot to include this, but after moving to this folder and correcting this error it worked. It seems the key was locating the script in the functions folder of the theme! I have posted an answer and given credit to the code you provided. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. glad you sorted it