# Add JavaScript to WordPress website without footer or header

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to add a piece of JS to my website that uses WordPress, but the page I am trying to make it affect does not use a header nor does it use a footer. From my little understanding, all the things I have looked up state that the header and footer are used in-order to load the JS. Is there another way to add the JS to my page without using the footer or header?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add javascript to a wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094915/how-to-add-javascript-to-a-wordpress-site)

Comment: @angel.bonev not really, just because I think that you need a header/footer for that to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome @Trobanko, in general you don't need a header or footer.
Just put your code in a `<script></script>` anywhere on the site.

However, in Wordpress the most plugins make use of the WP header and footer, but there are some that don't. [WP Coder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-coder/) seems to be the way to go.

I hope I could help you. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I think using <script> works, but when I paste in the code, it doesn't seem to work, this is what I have pasted in `<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
    $(".cart-page-desktop:not(:first)").remove();
    $(".cart-page-mobile:not(:first)").remove();
});
</script>`

Comment: @Trobanko try a `console.log("test")` before and another in the event to test if your code gets executed.

Comment: test runs, then i get this "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: I think in Wordpress you have to use jQuery. instead of $.

Comment: Yep, now both test's are going through, but the code just doesn't do it's function :(

Comment: Well, now you have to check the selectors. You can do that by running for example `$(".cart-page-desktop:not(:first)");` in the console and check, if you get at least one element